# JS map array of objects by specific property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. In each object is a property called `rate` (which is an array). I would like to map these to a new array to find the length of all rates available. Is the JS `map()` function appropriate here?

```javascript
const arraySample = [
  { rate: [ { price: 123 }, { price: 456 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 789 }, { price: 987 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 654 }, { price: 321 } ] }
]
```

**Desired Output**

```javascript
[ { price: 123 }, { price: 456 }, { price: 789 }, { price: 987 }, { price: 654 }, { price: 321 } ]
```

Return Length = 6

Answer (score 3):

`.flatMap` would be a better choice:

```js
const arraySample = [
  { rate: [ { price: 123 }, { price: 456 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 789 }, { price: 987 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 654 }, { price: 321 } ] }
];

const output = arraySample.flatMap(obj => obj.rate);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the length, and aren't going to use the array, you don't even need to map here.
A simple loop will suffice:

```js
const arraySample = [
  { rate: [ { price: 123 }, { price: 456 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 789 }, { price: 987 } ] },
  { rate: [ { price: 654 }, { price: 321 } ] }
];

let totalRates = 0;

for (arr of arraySample)
  totalRates += arr.rate.length;

console.log('Total rates:', totalRates);
```